# element2.focus() fired after element1.onblur() not working in Fx/Chrome/Safari - Salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, dom-events, visualforce

I am on Salesforce (visualforce) and using a custom autocomplete Javascript. My requirement is to trigger auto complete search on a text field `element2` as soon as a selection is made from suggestions on another text field `element1`.

Since I need to be able to scroll through the auto suggestions list using a keyboard, I need to have focus on the particular field. Am currently doing a `element2.focus()` just after a selection is made on `element1` and triggering the auto suggest search on `element2`.

Also, on these fields, when the search is running and the user manually focuses on the field, the auto suggestion collapses - this is an indication of cancelling the search. Because of this, I cannot trigger the search and *then* call `element2.focus()`

Here's what am experiencing in different browsers:

Chrome/Firefox 3.5, 4/Safari 5.0.3:

1. Select an option from suggestions under `element1`
2. Value in field changes
3. Suggestions collapse
4. Field blurs, but not sure where focus goes. Probably `window`

IE 8:

1. Select an option from suggestions under `element1`
2. Value in field changes
3. Suggestions collapse
4. Field blurs and `element2` takes focus
5. Search fires for this field

Also, the above difference in behaviour is only when am selecting using a mouse click. When using a keystroke (up/down then enter) this works as expected in all browsers. The same set of javascript methods are executed on both mouse and keyboard selection.

An interesting 'fix' I found for this is calling `element2.focus()` after, say, 100 ms using `setTimeout()`. Am guessing this is because `element1`'s onblur is disrupting `element2.focus()` but am not really happy using this.

Well, any ideas?

Code Samples:

```
//mouseclick handler

function handleMouseClick(event){

element1.value = (event.target)?event.target.textContent:event.srcElement.innerText;
callback();

// kills the children and hides the div containing the suggestions
hideAutoComplete();
}


function callback() {
element2.value = '';
element2.focus();
}
```

Comment: there you go @Matt. the callback also triggers the search on element2

Comment: cheers. Well I cant think of an answer :( but I want to know it

Comment: @Matt you could invest in a bounty if the current one expires :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use a framework? They really take the pain out of cross-browser compatibility for events. Here's a short example using jQuery that seems to do what you want. Any of the major frameworks would probably work just as well for this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing some JS behavior</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="fooForm">
            <label for="a">A: </label><input id="a"/><br />
            <label for="b">B: </label><input id="b"/><br />
        </form>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#b').focus(function(e) {
                alert("Focusing on b now.");
            });

            $('#a').blur(function(e) {
                alert("Doing my business on element A.");
                $('#b').focus();
                // Stop bubbling, just in case this got triggered by them clicking into B
                return false;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that helps but I can't use a framework for  various (non-technical) reasons

Comment: @LVS In that case, you may want to take a peak at the source for one of the major frameworks and see what you can learn; my cross-browser-fu is weak these days. YUI is BSD-licensed and jQuery is MIT, IIRC.